# Docker entrypoint script exit by subscript

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My container execute a script, dockerfile related:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

My entrypoint is in charge of generating webcode and also database.

```
    # check if database is already installed 
    echo "Does it execute? 3"
    databaseCode=$(php $PWD/admin/cli/check_database_schema.php)
    echo "Does it execute?"
    if [ $databaseCode -eq 2 ]; then
        echo >&2 "Installing database..."
    elif [ $databaseCode -eq 0 ]; then
        echo >&2 "Moodle Database found!"
    else
        echo >&2 "Could not install Moodle Database due to errors!"
    fi
    exec "$@"
```

check_database_schema.php exists with 2 as database is not still created:

Part of the code:

```
if ($options['help']) {
    echo $help;
    exit(0);
}

if (empty($CFG->version)) {
    echo "Database is not yet installed.\n";
    exit(2);
}
```

If I run my containers:

```
moodle        | Moodle Data directory found
moodle        | Moodle not found in /var/www/html - copying now...
moodle        | Complete! Moodle has been successfully copied to /var/www/html
moodle        | Starting Moodle Installation
moodle        | Does it execute? 3
moodle exited with code 2
```

It seems exit in php code also exit the main process. Any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
The start of my script had

```
#set -euo pipefail
```

Changed it to:

```
set -u
```

Comment: (You can also `set +e` to disable it for an individual command.)